# RetryPolicy on Web Api causes timeout

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-core-webapi, webapi, retrypolicy

I have a Web Api that invokes another web api call to get some information. In order to make the app more resilient, I implemented a HttpTransientErrorDetectionStrategy following the steps at: https://alexandrebrisebois.wordpress.com/2013/02/21/defining-an-http-transient-error-detection-strategy-for-rest-calls/

After that, I use code like below to invoke the other web app:

```
RetryPolicy _retryPolicy = new RetryPolicy<HttpTransientErrorDetectionStrategy>(
    new ExponentialBackoff(retryCount: 2, minBackoff: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0), maxBackoff: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), deltaBackoff: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)));

var _httpClient = new HttpClient
{
    BaseAddress = new Uri("http://www.microsoft.com")
};

HttpResponseMessage response = _retryPolicy.ExecuteAsync(async () => await _httpClient.GetAsync($"", HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead)).Result;
```

The _httpClient.GetAsync call gets stuck, and I have no idea why. If I remove the _retryPolicy, and just use _httpClient.GetAsync directly, it returns in a matter of seconds.

I have similar code on a console app, to invoke the same web app, and that is working fine, so this seems to be specific to the way I am using it in my web API. This is intended to be an app on Azure, but it happens when I debug locally as well. Does anybody have any idea why this is getting stuck? How can I debug this?

Thank you!

Comment: My initial feeling is that maybe it's some kind of async issue, when things just "get stuck". Do you get to the line in debug, but it never seems to finish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have similar code on a console app, to invoke the same web app, and that is working fine, so this seems to be specific to the way I am using it in my web API.

The code you posted is blocking right here:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = _retryPolicy.ExecuteAsync(...).Result;
```

[Don't block on async code](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html). Instead, use `await`:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await _retryPolicy.ExecuteAsync(...);
```

> If I remove the _retryPolicy, and just use _httpClient.GetAsync directly, it returns in a matter of seconds.

If your original code is blocking, and you *must* block on asynchronous code (for some reason), then you can either use the [`ConfigureAwait(false)` hack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2015/july/async-programming-brownfield-async-development):

```
HttpResponseMessage response = _retryPolicy.ExecuteAsync(async () => await _httpClient.GetAsync($"", HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead).ConfigureAwait(false)).Result;
```

or [elide `async`/`await`](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html):

```
HttpResponseMessage response = _retryPolicy.ExecuteAsync(() => _httpClient.GetAsync($"", HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead)).Result;
```

P.S. [Check out `DecorrelatedJitterBackoffV2`](https://github.com/Polly-Contrib/Polly.Contrib.WaitAndRetry#wait-and-retry-with-jittered-back-off).

Comment: Perfect, either of these suggestions solve my issue! Thank you!